# How to save custom fields with user data on Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I've created a "Account" class so i can get more columns on user information:

```
class Account(AbstractUser):

company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
company_department = models.CharField(max_length=50)
company_employees_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

I've also created a `form` with this data so i can receive the information on my view.

```
class AccountCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

company_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
company_department = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
company_employees_quantity = forms.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    model = Account
    fields = ('username', 'email')
```

The problem is when the client send the data though the form, i receive all the fields but only the "core" user information is inserted on the database.

```
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = AccountCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

If o add a method `form_valid` on on `view` o can save the data field by field like this:

```
class SignUpView(CreateView):
form_class = AccountCreationForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
template_name = 'signup.html'

def form_valid(self, form):
    if form.is_valid():
        account = form.save()
        account.company_name = form.cleaned_data["company_name"]
        account.company_department = form.cleaned_data["company_department"]
        account.company_employees_quantity = form.cleaned_data["company_employees_quantity"]
        account.save()

        return redirect(self.success_url)

    return super().form_invalid(form)
```

But this look weird to me? the view/form/model shouldn't save my "custom" fields automatically along with the "core" user info? How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define 'company_name', 'company_department' and 'company_employees_quantity' again, you can add them in the `fields` attribute.

Try the following:

```
class AccountCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = (
            'username',
            'email',
            'company_name',
            'company_department',
            'company_employees_quantity',
        )
```